# Call a function when Observer subscribes to an RxJS ipe

Tags: rxjs

I have an RxJS observable-producing method that works but it seems a bit hacky and I was wondering if it can be improved with better use of RxJs operators.

What I have implemented is an object cache (in an Angular service) where events are generated when objects are loaded, edited, or changed.  The event object looks like this:

```js
export interface DNodeEvent {
  type: 'load' | 'unload' | 'update' | 'create' | 'error';
  node: DNode;
}
```

So I have a method that generates an observable for components to use.  The caller provides an id/serial number and gets a stream of node objects.  My current code looks like this:

```js
  obById(id: number): Observable<DNode> {
    const unload = { type: 'unload' } as DNode;
    const pipeId =  this.nodeEvent$.pipe(
      filter(ne => ne.node.serial === id &&
        (ne.type === 'load' || ne.type === 'update')),
      map(ne => ne.node)
    );
    const pipeLoad = of(id).pipe(
      tap(loadTarget => this.loadId(loadTarget)),
      switchMap(loadTarget => of(unload)),
      filter(dn => dn.type === 'load')
    );
    return merge(pipeId, pipeLoad);
  }
```

The `pipeId` observable generates the stream of nodes and I don't see what to improve there.

However the function of the `pipeload` observable is to call the `this.loadId` method which triggers the generation of an event out of the `nodeEvent$` Subject.  If it finds the requested object in the cache it sends an event immediately otherwise it will subscribe to an `http` observable to fetch it from the server then generate the event.

The only problem I have is that I don't want `pipeLoad` to emit anything.  But I ended up putting the `switchMap`/`filter` operators there to close complete the `of` operator.  Also I had to stick the awkward `unload` constant in there to keep the compiler from complaining about type matching.

Is there a more elegant/robust way of getting this done?

Comment: looks like pipeLoad will never emit because of the filter? why don't you just execute the `this.loadId(id)` and remove all the `pipeLoad` observable logic and just return `pipeId`?

Comment: @MauroAguilar #1:  The this.loadId method must be called or this.nodeEvent$ will never emit anything.   #2: loadId must be called AFTER the caller to obById subscribes to the observer it returns.  Otherwise the subscriber will miss the initial event.

Answer (score 2):

You can put `ignoreElements()` to mute the stream yet still subscribe to it.

```
const pipeLoad = of(id).pipe(
  tap(loadTarget => this.loadId(loadTarget)),
  switchMap(loadTarget => of(unload)),

  ignoreElements()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the purpose of doing this:

```
const unload = { type: 'unload' } as DNode;

...
const pipeLoad = of(id).pipe(
  tap(loadTarget => this.loadId(loadTarget)),
  switchMap(loadTarget => of(unload)),          <--- ?
  filter(dn => dn.type === 'load')              <--- ?
);

return merge(pipeId, pipeLoad);
```

wouldn't it be the same to do this?

```
obById(id: number): Observable<DNode> {
  const pipeId$ =  this.nodeEvent$.pipe(
    filter(ne => ne.node.serial === id &&
      (ne.type === 'load' || ne.type === 'update')),
      map(ne => ne.node)
    );

  this.loadId(id);

  return pipeId$;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Using a `BehaviorSubject` instead of a `Subject` using the code suggested above may solve the issue. I've tried to reproduce your code in Stackblitz, check it out [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-kdcv9j?devtoolsheight=60).

Comment: @MaruoAguliar what you suggest does not work.   The caller of the function will get an observable that never emits a next if the requested object is in the cache.  The reason is that the loadId method will finish execution before the pipeId$ is returned.    So the aim is to not call loadId until after the pipeId$ observable is subscribed to.

Comment: @MaruoAguilar the purpose of the marked statements is so that the pipeLoad constant is of type Observable<DNode>.  Without that the compiler complains.

Comment: @AlanObject I think I know what you mean, the subject would trigger before subscribing to `pipeId$` and therefore any subscription afterwards would miss that last emission, am I right? if so, I think you could fix it by replacing the `Subject` by a `BehaviorSubject` to ensure that you get the last emission of the subject even if it was already fired. Be aware that the observable returned by this function will remain active emitting values that pass the filter unless you add a `first()` operator in the pipeline to ensure that the observable emits only once and then completes.